# Wordpress: Include variable in add_query_arg

Tags: php, wordpress

Using this:

```
echo add_query_arg( 'hello', '$var', get_permalink(9) );
```

On the following page (permalink(9)), when I

```
echo $_GET['hello'];
```

I get $var, not the contents of the variable.

Is there a way to make sure it's a string before I add it to add_query_arg?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing it in using single quotes, which will not parse the variable. It's sending in a string "$var" instead of the actual variable.

Use no quotes and try again.

To check if it's a string, use `is_string()` to return a T/F value, and if true, execute.